# How to handle dataframe skipping column in output if None?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Dataframe is missing column in output. How do I handle this?

My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []
        self.game = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []

    def append(self, score):
        pass


def get_urls(browser, landing_page):
    browser.get(landing_page)
    urls = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in
            browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                '.next-games-date > a:nth-child(1), .next-games-date > a:nth-child(n+3)')]

    return urls


def parse_data(html):
    df = pd.read_html(html, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'table-matches'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})

    if main is None:
        return None

    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[0].text
    game_data = GameData()

    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            country = row[1].split('»')[0]
            continue
        game_time = row[1]
        game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]     
        score = None    
        if score is not None:    
            return row[3]    
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(game_time)
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(count[1].text)
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(score) #This should be score if available else NaN
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])



    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
    urls = []
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    results = None
    urls = get_urls(browser, start_url)
    urls.insert(0, start_url)

    for number, url in enumerate(urls):
        if number > 0:
            browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        game_data = parse_data(html)

        if game_data is None:
            continue

        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)

        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```

The [score] column does not have data. How do I handle this?
I would like to return NaN if no value and if present, return value. The above code is skipping the column altogether. How di i handle it?

Since SO wants me to explain further and since I have mostly code, I would like to know ho do I build this dataframe correctly?

Comment: Which element is containing score value please mention and also if score is not `None`  it should append the value instead of return it dont you think so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting score as None and then immediately checking if it is not None, which of course it is.

You could try :

```
from math import nan
score = row[3] if row[3] else nan
game_data.score.append(score)
```